# Picking more than one random from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random, return

I wrote this function:

```js
function randomProduct(num) {
  var iter = num;
  for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    var rand = recommendedProducts[Math.floor(Math.random() * recommendedProducts.length)];
    return rand
  }
}
```

Which is supposed to pull from the `recommendedProducts` array however many are needed when the function is called. So basically `randomProduct(1)` would *pull 1* and `randomProduct(4)` would *pull 4*, etc.

However no matter what number I enter in there when I test is through the console, I always only get 1 array item returned.

```
console.log(randomProduct(1));
console.log(randomProduct(2));
console.log(randomProduct(3));
console.log(randomProduct(4));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run it in a debugger or mentally. You return inside the loop so it always returns one item and quits.

Comment: Is expected result an array or string?

Comment: Expected result is a string

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Tried it with the return statement outside the for loop as well, didn't make a difference.

Comment: @SteveMedley It doesn't matter if its outside, you are only assigning a single random value in that variable, it would just do so many times overwriting the last value. It's impossible to have more than 1 with that code.

Comment: You need to store the values and return them in an array, like Shlomi's answer. If you return one value, you'll get one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function randomProduct(num) {
    var iter = num;
    var rand ="";
    for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    rand += recommendedProducts[Math.floor(Math.random() * recommendedProducts.length)];
    }
    return rand

 }
```

as @Steve Medley said the result expected to be string. so if recommendedProducts contains some string you should add this string in each iteration of loop to your result and return it after your loop has finished( also this is what i have understood from question)

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function randomProduct(num) {
    var iter = num;
    var randomArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
     randomArray.push(recommendedProducts[Math.floor(Math.random() * recommendedProducts.length)]);
    }
    return randomArray.join(); // returns it as a string
}
```

First you need to append the items to an array using `push`

Second you need to return outside of the loop, if you retrun from the inside of the loop you break the function after the first iteration.

Comment: as @Steve Medley said result  expected to be string not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The `return rand` take you off the function at the first result.

You can remove the loop, just return the rand, and call the function 4 times.

If you want the function to return array of random numbers, instead of `return rand`, push the results to new array and return the array when the for loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, variable `rand` will be given the value equal to the value it's last iterations output, you need to return array of objects instead of single object to get desired result.